# Android: ImageView.SetVisibility not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, android-viewpager

I am writing some code to make previously loaded images visible once a ViewPager selects the containing fragment. However, I can not understand why the code for ImageView.setVisibility() doesn't ever seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) 
        {

            ScreenSlidePageFragment myFrag = (ScreenSlidePageFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(i);
            myFrag.removeImage();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) 
        {

            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
            {
                ScreenSlidePageFragment myFrag = (ScreenSlidePageFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(mPagerAdapter.getItemPosition(null));
                myFrag.loadImage();
            }

        }
    });
```

The code for loadImage and removeImage is below. It is part of a class that extends fragment.

```
public void loadImage()
{
    if (background != null)
    {
        background.clearAnimation();
        background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void removeImage()
{
    if (background != null)
    {
        background.clearAnimation();
        background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think when you use onPageScrollStateChanged you are trying to get fragment from viewpager.
however the position is seems wrong when you getItem(int position)

to manage fragments I can suggest you to use
ArrayList or HashMap then
when you want to call methods. you should do like

```
@Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        list.get(position).loadImage();


        if(position>0&&list.get(position-1)!=null){
        list.get(position-1). removeImage()
      }
        if(position+1<list.size()&&list.get(position+1)!=null){
        list.get(position+1). removeImage()
      }
}
```

I don't recommend this because of memory Issue.
if the size of list is small (about 3~10 it's okay I think)

-----10.24 additional answer
I recommend you to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter
and override getItemPosition

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
}
```

it will make your viewpager to destory fragment you don't use.
and create fragment each time when you see.

and in ScreenSlidePageFragment
load image when onCreate or onResume or onCreateView

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    loadImage();
    super.onResume();
}
```

override onDestoy method.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    removeImage();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my application has to be scalable and memory is already at a premium. I can expect many fragments, much more than 10.

Comment: Also, I didn't include it here, but I have had output that indicates that the fragments were being accessed in the correct order. As long as this isn't some sort of asynchronous problem. I can post output if you like.

Comment: This looks like it will do everything I want. Will test it for performance.

Comment: Implemented and tested the code shown above. Ran it on my target device and was unable to perceive see any difference from when I used the original code. I am beginning to think that there is something fundamental that I don't understand... like maybe setVisibility() doesn't apply to imageView the way I think it does?

Comment: I just tried something simple: override onCreateView to setVisibility() on the image immediately after it is created. This does nothing. Set the XML element for the image to always be invisible. This does nothing. I don't understand why this would be the case.

Comment: it would be solve if you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
when the item in the adapter is changed you'd better to call this method to reflect to the window you see.

if is not the case. Please show me the xml file, and Fragment source please;; I know it's been long time but I want to help .

Answer (score 0):

try this code
background.setVisibility(View.GONE);
instead of
background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Wouldn't this make it impossible to make the image visible again? I don't want to get rid of the imageView, I want it to be invisible. I could expect to change this status many times if needed.

Comment: The View.GONE option doesn't physically remove the image, but rather it removes it from the screen area where the image would take up.  If you use View.GONE and there are views below it in a vertical LinearLayout for example, those views below will move up, since that area is now available whereas using View.INVISIBLE will still take up screen area even though you can't see what's there.